# Setting up boot scripts for BeagleBone/Angstrom

Tags: boot, angstrom

I'm working on setting up the pinmux on a BeagleBone so that I can access multiple UARTS.  The OS is Angstrom Linux (the demo image, if that helps).  I have a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Configuring Pinmux"

echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/uart1_txd
echo 20> /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/uart1_rxd

echo "UART 1 (TX):"
cat /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/uart1_txd
echo

echo "UART 1 (RX):"
cat /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/uart1_rxd
echo

echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/spi0_d0
echo 21> /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/spi0_sclk

echo "UART 2 (TX):"
cat /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/spi0_d0
echo

echo "UART 2 (RX):"
cat /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/spi0_sclk
echo
```

Which sets up the UARTS for use.  Now, I want this script to run on boot, so that I don't have to mess with it every time.  Where should I put this/ make a link in order to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after much digging, I found the correct way to do this.  Angstrom uses systemd to launch things on boot, so putting things in /etc/rc**n**.d doesn't work correctly.  Instead, you make a service, tell systemd about it, and then it works automagically.

In /lib/systemd/system, I created a file called  pinmux.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Setting up Pinmux

[Service]
ExecStart = /home/**username**/pinmux.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This calls the shell script in my home directory called pinmux.sh, which does all the setting, as noted in my question.

To enable it, call `systemctl enable pinmux.service`, followed by 
`systemctl start pinmux.service`.

Now, the script will be called on boot.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to "systemctl start" within the image creation. Apart from the dirty way of creating a link in /etc/systemd/system

Answer (score 2):

Just checked Angstrom Linux, it's Debian based, so copy these lines to `/etc/rc.local` would work for you:

```
echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/uart1_txd
echo 20> /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/uart1_rxd
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/spi0_d0
echo 21> /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/spi0_sclk
```

Answer (score 1):

As a newbie, I know two ways to do that, easy one comes: in `/etc/rc5.d` you can see some files whose names starting with some numbers which assigns who is going to start first, and they are started from the first number to last number respectively. Put your script here with the last number:

```
vi /etc/rc5.d/S25yourScript.sh
```

I assume S25 the last number :)  paste your script here and exit. When you reboot once your script will work

Comment: Don't use a file in /etc/rc*.d, use a link instead, put the real file to /etc/init.d

Comment: yes thats true, im sorry. You should put the same script to /etc/init.d also. Without it, its not working. Thank you Warl0ck